# Copy data from one column to another from different tables in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to copy data to column A in Table1 from column B in Table2. Rows for column A are empty and there are exists other columns in Table1 with already populated data. So I need to grab the whole column B from Table2 and insert all those values in column A in Table1. The two table are completely identical, except that column A has no values at all.

How do I do this in sqlite3?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT B,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
  FROM TABLE2
```

Use NULL as the placeholder for however many columns you can't populate from TABLE2, assuming TABLE1 columns allow NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET A = (SELECT B FROM TABLE2 WHERE ...)
```

Come to think of it, if the tables are truly identical, why do you need two of them? In any case you can also do this:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM TABLE1;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (A, col1, col2, ...) SELECT (B, col2, col2, ...) FROM TABLE2;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This did not work either...It insert the same value (value from first row in Table2) in every row in Table1. For every row there is a different value in Table2 that needs to be mapped over to column A in Table1. So how do I do this?

Comment: You need a where clause to match the rows; see revised answer above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (A) SELECT B FROM TABLE2